# How to handle back button pressed for UWP

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-mobile

I used to use hardware button API in Windows Phone 8.1 XAML. However, in UWP some devices don't have back button. How do I adapt to the new app model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use BackRequested event to handle back request:

```
SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += OnBackRequested;

if (App.MasterFrame.CanGoBack)
{
    rootFrame.GoBack();
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Where is located this `SystemNavigationManager`? I am unable to locate it.

Comment: in `Windows.UI.Core` namespace. VS should suggest you that.

Comment: Ok. It might be because I am targeting 8.1.

Answer (score 5):

**Little bit explained answer.**
You can used [SystemNavigationManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.systemnavigationmanager) of `Windows.UI.Core` namespace

## For Single Page

---

If you just want to handle navigation for single page. Follow the following steps

**Step 1**. Use namespace `Windows.UI.Core`

```
using Windows.UI.Core;
```

**Step 2.** Register back request event for current view. Best place for this is main constructor of class after `InitializeComponent()`.

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    //register back request event for current view
    SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += MainPage_BackRequested;
}
```

**Step 3.** Handle BackRequested event

```
private void Food_BackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    if (Frame.CanGoBack)
    {
        Frame.GoBack();
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

## For Complete Application at one place for single `rootFrame`

---

Best place for handling all backbutton for all Views is `App.xaml.cs`

**Step 1**. Use namespace `Windows.UI.Core`

```
using Windows.UI.Core;
```

**Step 2.** Register back request event for current view. Best place for this is `OnLaunched` just before `Window.Current.Activate`

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += OnBackRequested;
    Window.Current.Activate();
}
```

**Step 3.** Handle BackRequested event

```
private void OnBackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
    if (rootFrame.CanGoBack)
    {
        rootFrame.GoBack();
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

---

References- [Handle back button pressed in UWP](https://developerinsider.co/handle-back-button-pressed-in-uwp/)

Hope this is helpful to someone!

Comment: I found this answer useful for preventing the app from exiting when pressing "B" on an Xbox controller on Xbox. I just had to make `e.Handled = true` always.

Answer (score 0):

The above code is exactly correct but you have to add object of frame in rootFrame variable. Below are given:

```
private Frame _rootFrame;
 protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
 { 
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        if (Window.Current.Content==null)
        {
            _rootFrame = new Frame();
        }
}
```

And pass this _rootFrame to OnBackRequested method. Like:

```
 private void OnBackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs 
 {
       if (_rootFrame.CanGoBack)
       {
            _rootFrame.GoBack();
            e.Handled = true;
       }
 }
```