# How to Override hardware button click

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am using VS 2015 community version on Windows 10 PC to develop windows 8.1 app

The problem:
How to override the hardware button click ?

It seems below can not be used :

```
using windows.phone.ui.input

Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
```

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle back button pressed for UWP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33571836/how-to-handle-back-button-pressed-for-uwp)

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing me to the right place.