# How to pause UWP app when the user presses the back button on root page?

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I am trying to find a way how to pause UWP application (not exit). The idea is to show a warning dialog with two options (Yes or No) when the user is on the root page and presses the back button (physical one).

I have been trying to find a solution online and the closest thing I found was calling - `Application.Current.Exit` in the UWP project.

Comment: What do you mean by "pause" an app? This might be helpful - [How to handle back button press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33571836/how-to-handle-back-button-pressed-for-uwp)

Comment: I think that is the state that the app goes to when the user "exists" the app by pressing the back button on the root page of the stack. That causes the user to be taken to the OS - out of the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have a confirmation dialog when user presses the back button, you need to handle the `SystemNavigationManager.BackRequested` event. You will mark it as `Handled` and present the user with a confirmation dialog. If the user presses `Yes`, you can then force exit the application with `Application.Current.Exit()`.

However this presents the problem that the app is not suspended but terminated, which means it is not paused. That's because presenting the dialog is an `async` task and event handler must return immediately. You can manually call your suspend logic to save state, but there is no way to programmatically trigger the system based suspend flow...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Calling Application.Current.Exit is not ideal for me. Do you know if the back button can be triggered programmatically? My idea is to invoke a back button after the user selects &quot;Yes&quot;. That is basically the scenario that the user experiences without the confirmation dialog.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to do so programmatically as of now... Only user can trigger the system back navigation

Comment: Thank you again for your help. I am accepting your answer although the solution is not ideal in my scenario (i.e. terminating the app) but I do understand that currently it is impossible to be done. :)